# How to set a key in .properties file using installer variable in installer4j (5.1.14)

Tags: java, install4j, properties-file

I am trying to build an installer for my application which asks port-number, application data directory and so on..

I have tried to use "**Replace installer variable in text files**" action with a **configurable form** which have text field which have the information I want to store in .properties file.

I tried to put variable in the .properties file in following different ways with no luck..

```
http.port = ${portnum}  or
http.port = ${installer:portnum} or
http.port = portnum
```

etc. *portnum* is the name of the variable for the text field (which stores the value given in the text) but none of the code works here. Generated file have the same lines without taking values from the variable.

I wanted to know where I am making mistake. I am a newbee to install4j so elaborate answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Install4j 6? It has a "Write properties to file" action: https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/whatsnew6.html

Comment: Yes I know. but in our project we are using Java 1.6 and install4j 6.0 requires minimum java 1.7. This is the reason I am not able to use 6.0

Comment: Using Java 1.6 is a bad idea for all kinds of reasons, but I guess you know that. How about using "Write text to a file" to append the relevant key (assuming it's not already there)?

Comment: I have tried that also but it does not add anything to file. if I set an error message it gives me com.installer4j.runtime.beans.action.writetextaction failed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Yes I know. but in our project we are using Java 1.6 and install4j 6.0 
>   requires minimum java 1.7.

That is only the case for the install4j IDE, but not for the installed application and the installer where the minimum version is 1.6. So you should be fine with install4j 6 and the "Write properties to file" action.

Otherwise the syntax

```
${installer:portnum}
```

should work with the "Replace installer variable in text files" action if the portnum variable is defined.

Comment: Can you tell how I should define the portnum variable? I have given just the variable name in properties list of text field. ( and used Set a Variable action along with that)

Comment: If the text field form component has its "Variable name" property set to "portnum", you don't need a "Set a variable" action. You can look at the log file at .install4j/installation.log in the installation directory to check how and when variables change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing following...

Rather than adding action to the screen, I added action **"write text to a file"** in installation process and I added the variable as

```
http.port = ${installer:portnum}
```

this solved my problem. Thanks to everyone who contributed.